# Python, .csv read matching rows for specific columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of values like this

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

And I have a .csv file that has the following data

```
ID    Amount    Address
1     5.1       oergbe
3     2.4       oabvae
5     1.8       vuvuow
```

I can open the .csv and read column[0]

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as NN:
    reader = csv.reader(NN)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)

csv_ids = (columns[0])
```

and I can find matches

```
match_ids = set(ids).intersection(csv_ids)
```

So now match_ids = [1, 3] then how do I pull column[1] Amount and column[2] Address, only for rows of `match_ids`

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by *pull*? you want to get those columns or what? If you've already preserved the columns you can use a simple indexing to get them.

Comment: yes so now 2 new variables match_amount and match_address, match_amount = [5.1, 2.4] and match_address = ['oergbe', 'oabvae']

Comment: `[row for row in columns if row[0] in match_ids]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a simple way by preserving the rows that their first item exist in your `ids`. And as a more elegant way you can use a dictionary for preserving them:

```
final_result = {}
with open(filename, 'rb') as NN:
    reader = csv.reader(NN)
    reader.next()
    for id_, amount, address in reader:
        if id_ in ids:
            final_result.setdefault('amount', []).append(amount)
            final_result.setdefault('address', []).append(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only want the lines with an Id which are in `ids`, and you only need columns `Amount` and `Address`.

If this is true then this code does that:

```
import csv

ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
filename = 'data.csv'
result = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as NN:
    reader = csv.reader(NN)
    reader.next()
    for id, amount, address in reader:
        if int(id) in ids:
            columns.append((amount,address))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('5.1', 'oergbe'), ('2.4', 'oabvae')]
```

Note: The csv parsing only works when the csv is looking like this (in your example you had spaces, which won't work unless you add some options to the `csv.reader` call:

```
ID,Amount,Address
1,5.1,oergbe
3,2.4,oabvae
5,1.8,vuvuow
```

This is now a list of `set`s, you might want a list of `dict`s instead.